# set line between qtreewidget items

Tags: c++, qt

I have a `QTreeWidget` that items append to it dynamically, I want to set lines between them, I have first pictures and I want it to be like the second one, but I don't know how doing it?
thank you in advance!

[image: [I have this tree]

[image: [I want my tree to be like this]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well you can experiment with stylesheets:

```
treeWidget->setStyleSheet("QTreeWidget::item { border-bottom: 1px solid black;}");
```

But I am not sure if can get exactly the look you want. You can also subclass [QStyledItemDelegate](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qstyleditemdelegate.html) and provide your own `sizeHint()` and `paint()` implementations.

Answer (score 0):

If You need to select items, following works a little better I think:

```
  QString style = "QTreeWidget::item:!selected "
    "{ "
      "border: 1px solid gainsboro; "
      "border-left: none; "
      "border-top: none; "
    "}"
    "QTreeWidget::item:selected {}";
  allergiesListView->setStyleSheet(style);
```